# Question about Facebook API login-button (more about a feature of the login-button)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, browser, authentication

When using the facebook login API, when you click the login button, it opens up the request for permission browser page. I was wondering, how does facebook open up this browser? Also, the browser used for the request for permission page does not let you change URLs, the size is fixed in the beginning, and the browser is very clean (w/o bookmarks or tabs). Is this feature to open up such a browser something that is in the standard html/javascript already? or is it something that facebook made themselves?

To illustrate what I'm talking about, press the fb login at the top of this page:

http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

specs allows the modifications you're asking about.

Example:

`window.open('http://facebooksurlforlogginin', 'Login', 'titlebar=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,width=500,height=400');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open